# PHP Separate comma array into variable / values

Tags: php

I have a string in a table field that looks like this:

```
part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,part4=200000
```

To call it from the table I do this:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


        $row['mystring'];


}
```

My problem is that I need to separate the parts into variables for example:

From this:

```
part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,someothername=200000
```

To This:

```
$part1 = '1';
$part2 = 'S';
$part3 = 'Y';
$someothername = '200000';
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something called 'Variable variables'. You can declare the content of a variable as a variable, if you use double dollar sign, instead of a single one. For example:

```
$fruit = "apple";
$$fruit = "this is the apple variable";
echo $apple;
```

It would output the following:

> this is the apple variable

You have to be a bit more tricky with defining variables from an array, as you'd have to enclode the original variable in curly brackets. (for example: `${$fruit[0]}`)

So the answer to your question is:

```
$parts = "part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,someothername=200000";
$parts_array = explode(",", $parts);
foreach ($parts_array as $value) {
    $temp = explode("=", $value);
    ${$temp[0]} = $temp[1];
}
echo "$part1, $part2, $part3, $someothername";
```

PHPFiddle link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/adyb-ug5n

Answer (score 6):

Use like this

```
parse_str( str_replace(",", "&", "part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,someothername=200000") );
```

Use with there name like:

```
$part1 // return 1
$part2 // return S
$part3 // return Y
```

works like you want, see the [demo](http://codepad.org/vLaEtAy2)

Answer (score 1):

First split string:

```
$s = "part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,part4=200000";
$a = explode(",",$s);
```

then foreach part of string ("part1=1"...) create an array and explode as variable:

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
 $tmp = explode("=",$v);
 $tmp = array($tmp[0]=>$tmp[1]);
 extract($tmp);
}
echo $part1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Double `explode` your string to get the wanted field :

```
$string ="part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,someothername=200000";

foreach (explode(',', $string) as $parts) {
  $part = explode('=', $parts);
  $array[$part[0]] = $part[1];
}

var_dump($array);
```

Output :

```
 array(4) {
  ["part1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["part2"]=>
  string(1) "S"
  ["part3"]=>
  string(1) "Y"
  ["someothername"]=>
  string(6) "200000"
}
```

I wouldn't suggest the use of variable variables to get the output as :

```
$part1 = ...
$part2 = ...
```

Using an array is probably the easier and safest way to do here. As suggested in my comment, it avoid potential conflicts with variable names.

Comment: You could use extract() at the end to get your variables, but I would also stick with an array

Comment: @DavidJones True, I should have specify that in that case, it's better to avoid to directly name the variables to avoid possible conflicts with already existing variables with the same name.

Comment: Yep thats true, I agree with you about keeping the array but the OP wanted variables :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP 5.3+ you can use array_map

```
<?php

$string = 'part1=1,part2=S,part3=Y,part4=200000';

array_map(function($a){
    $tmp = explode('=', $a, 2);
    global ${$tmp[0]}; //make vars available outside of this function scope
    ${$tmp[0]} = $tmp[1]; 
}, explode(',', $string));

//Variables available outside of array_map scope
echo $part1 . '<br>';
echo $part2 . '<br>';
echo $part3 . '<br>';
echo $part4 . '<br>';

?>
```